# How to pass the value of variables from inside an override method to outside it in Android studio

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am having trouble, measuring the height and width of a programatically created LinearLayout in android studio, I adopted the following solution

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context.this);

layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int width = layout.getWidth();
            int height = layout.getHeight();
        }
}

}
```

the problem I am having is that I cant retrieve the value of these variables outside the override method. I have tried creating separate variables outside the override method like this

```
final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context.this);
final int width;
final int height;

layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            width = layout.getWidth();
            height = layout.getHeight();
        }
}

Log.d(TAG, "width is "+ width.ToString())
```

but even in this case width = 0 if called outside the override method. So my question is, is there a way to pass the value of variables outside an override method or is there a different way of measuring the height/width of a layout when it is called in an onCreate method

Comment: [have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Answer (score 0):

Declare Both width and height outside onCreate method

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
int width;
int height;
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context.this);

    layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            width = layout.getWidth();
            height = layout.getHeight();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context.this); it should be like final LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);  check if this is the mistake